# XML encode/decode class in PHP

Tags: php, xml

Can anybody suggest a good and stable class to encode and decode XML in PHP?

## edit

found this example on php.net, but can't make it work.. no error msgs is returned

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement();
$sxe->addAttribute('type', 'documentary');

$movie = $sxe->addChild('movie');
$movie->addChild('title', 'PHP2: More Parser Stories');
$movie->addChild('plot', 'This is all about the people who make it work.');

$characters = $movie->addChild('characters');
$character  = $characters->addChild('character');
$character->addChild('name', 'Mr. Parser');
$character->addChild('actor', 'John Doe');

$rating = $movie->addChild('rating', '5');
$rating->addAttribute('type', 'stars');

echo $sxe->asXML();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SimpleXML](http://php.net/SimpleXML) would probably be the easiest. Example:

```
<root>
   <node>
      <sub>Text</sub>
   </node>
</root>
```

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('xml_file.xml', 0, true);
echo $xml->node->sub; // Displays "Text"
```

**Edit:**

In response to your code that isn't working, you need to include a root node in the initiation of the class:

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement('<root />');
```

Comment: @clarkk: You would use methods such as [`SimpleXMLElement::addChild()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php) to add new nodes to the XML object.

Comment: @clarkk: No, as XML doesn't have arrays; it has nodes with children. Therefore, you must make your own function to transform your array to XML data.

Comment: ok.. how can I check if it is installed on the server? it doesnt seems to work for me

Comment: @clarkk: Try creating a new `SimpleXMLElement` class. If it says the class can't be found, you need to install it.

Comment: found it.. SimpleXML
Simplexml support enabled
Revision  $Revision: 299424 $
Schema support  enabled ... but I can't make it work.. will update my qustion in a moment

Answer (score -1):

By encode/decode do you mean write/read? XML is not code, just markup. There is something called character/entity encoding for XML, though.

PHP has basically two class or libraries to work with. SimpleXML and DOMElement. You'll have to check your phpinfo to see if they are enabled and php.ini to enable them.